# Multiple Timers On A Single Page In A Meteor Application

Tags: javascript, meteor, countdown

I am trying to display multiple timers on a template. My template onCreated function is given below

```
   Template.viewTeamTermPaper.onCreated(function(){
     let template = Template.instance();
     template.subscribe('getTeamTermPaper');
     template.lastDateSubmit = new ReactiveVar()
     template.timeInterval = new ReactiveVar();
     template.timeLapse = new ReactiveVar()
     template.autorun(function () {
        if (template.lastDateSubmit.get()){
           template.timeInterval.set(setInterval(function() {
           let todayDate = new Date()
           //Session.set("time" , todayDate);
           template.timeLapse.set(getTimeRemaining(template.lastDateSubmit.get()));
        //Session.set("timeLapse" , timeLapse);
   } , 1000));
 }
```

});

});

I am displaying the each instance of the template with an helper called lastDate().

```
   Template.viewTeamTermPaper.helpers({
     lastDate(){
     let papers =  TeamTermPaper.find({}).fetch();
     return papers.map(function(paper){
     let obj = {}
     obj.paper = paper;
     Template.instance().lastDateSubmit.set(paper.last_submission_date);
     obj.time = Template.instance().timeLapse.get()
  //arr.push(obj)
     return obj
});

//return arr;
```

}

});

I have a function which calculates the elapsed time.

```
     function getTimeRemaining (endtime){
        let t = Date.parse(endtime) - new Date();
        let seconds = ("0" + Math.floor((t/1000) % 60)).slice(-2);
        let minutes = ("0" + Math.floor((t/1000/60) % 60)).slice(-2);
        let hours =   ("0" + Math.floor((t/(1000 * 60 * 60)) %   24)).slice(-2);
        let days = Math.floor(t/(1000*60*60*24));

        if (t <= 0){
            //clearInterval(timeInterval);
        }

        return {
            'total' : t,
            'days'  : days,
            'hours' : hours,
            'minutes': minutes,
            'seconds' : seconds
        }
```

}

This is how i out put the instance of the template

```
  <template name="viewTeamTermPaper">
    {{#each lastDate}}
        {{> studentViewTeamPaper}}
    {{/each}}
  </template>
```

My problem is i have the same timer for each item that is contained in the lastDate helper instead of different count down timers. I was thinking maybe for each item in my collection i should create a reactive variable that can be stored in an array. I don't know how to go about this line of thought. Any help is really appreciated.

```
 <template name="studentViewTeamPaper">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 card">
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered">

               <thead>
                 <tr>
                  <th class="text-danger">Term Paper Name</th>
                  <th class="text-danger">View</th>
                  <th class="text-danger">Count Down</th>
                </tr>
               </thead>


             <tbody>

               <tr>
                  <td>

                      {{paper_name}}


                  </td>

                  <td>
                      {{last_submission_date}}

                  </td>

                  <td></td>
              </tr>

            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>


     </div>
   </div>
 </template>
```

Comment: Can you provide your code for the template `studentViewTeamPaper`?

Comment: @jordanwillis i have added the code. Thank you

Comment: You're trying to control everything from the parent template instead of from the individual item template. If you define the countdown timer at the lower level template then you'll automatically get a different timer for each. Also look at the [remcoder:chronos](https://atmospherejs.com/remcoder/chronos) package which makes time reactive.

Comment: @MichelFloyd your suggestion worked. Please can you write it as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks for your time .

Comment: ok, posted as answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to control everything from the parent template instead of from the individual item template. If you define the countdown timer at the lower level `studentViewTeamPaper` template then you'll automatically get a different timer for each.

Also look at the [remcoder:chronos](https://atmospherejs.com/remcoder/chronos) package which makes time reactive.